# position of await in statement syntax clarification

Tags: javascript, syntax, async-await

I saw this code snippet today and this is the first time I have seen await in this position. I would have never thought to put it here.

```
for await (const req of s) {
  req.rspond({body: “Hello world\n” });
}
```

I would have put it before req (the actual async command)

```
for (const req of s) {
  await req.rspond({body: “Hello world\n” });
}
```

I used a similar pattern in my puppeteer code.

```
  for (let i of a) {
      await page.click(sel);
      await page.waitFor(wait);
}
```

My question is, would this still work correctly if I coded it like this?

```
  for await (let i of a) {
      page.click(sel);
      page.waitFor(wait);
}
```

And apply the await to all async commands? Where does await belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - `for await` is a *special* way for interacting with objects which expose an async iterable interface:

```js
const wait = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
const obj = {
  async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      // fetching item...
      await wait();
      yield i;
    }
  }
};

(async () => {
  for await (const item of obj) {
    console.log(item);
  }
})();
```

If you have a *normal* iterator, like you do with `const req of s`, and you need to call an asynchronous function for each item yielded by the iterator, then your current code is still the only way to do it, eg:

```
for (const req of s) {
  await req.rspond({body: “Hello world\n” });
}
```

Async iterators are useful for when the items being yielded are generated asynchronously. They don't imply anything about the items *after* they're yielded from the generator.